# Material UI Date-Picker: 3 Letter Abbreviation Month showing placeholder as "MMMM" instead of "MMM"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently using the latest version of @mui/x-date-pickers (6.16.0).
As seen in the code below, I'm formatting the text field input in "MMM DD, YYYY" style. However, when the date picker field has no current value, the placeholder text instead shows as "MMMM DD, YYYY", with 4 Ms instead of 3. I've tried different placeholder values, as well as assigning placeholder and default values to the child TextField and Input components of a date picker with no luck.

```
<DatePicker
                  disabled={disabled}
                  value={moment(displayAsLocal(displayDate?.toString()))}
                  onChange={(value, context) => handleDateChange(value.toDate(), context)}
                  format="MMM DD, YYYY"
                  minDate={moment(adjustedDateProps.minDate)}
                  maxDate={moment(adjustedDateProps.maxDate)}
                />
```

Does this seem familiar to anyone?

Changing the format string to match other layouts, with no luck

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [MUI team](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/8526#issuecomment-1499283578):

> That's the expected behavior. When a section is empty, it shows a
> placeholder which is not necessarily the format token. Here for month,
> the default is 4 letters for words and 2 letters for numbers
>
> ```
> // From src/locales/enUS.ts fieldMonthPlaceholder: (params) =>
> (params.contentType === 'letter' ? 'MMMM' : 'MM'),
> ```
>
> You can modify
> this behavior by providing custom localeText:
>
> ```
> // Field section placeholders fieldYearPlaceholder: (params) =>
> 'Y'.repeat(params.digitAmount), fieldMonthPlaceholder: (params) =>
> (params.contentType === 'letter' ? 'MMMM' : 'MM'),
> fieldDayPlaceholder: () => 'DD', fieldWeekDayPlaceholder: (params) =>
> (params.contentType === 'letter' ? 'EEEE' : 'EE'),
> fieldHoursPlaceholder: () => 'hh', fieldMinutesPlaceholder: () =>
> 'mm', fieldSecondsPlaceholder: () => 'ss', fieldMeridiemPlaceholder:
> () => 'aa',
> ```

So in your case:

```
// Whatever locale you need -- U.S. english for the example
import { enUS } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/locales';

const usLocale = enUS.components.MuiLocalizationProvider.defaultProps.localeText;

// In your app's LocalizationProvider implementation
<LocalizationProvider
      dateAdapter={...}
      localeText={{
        ...usLocale,
        fieldMonthPlaceholder: (params) =>
          params.contentType === "letter" ? "MMM" : "MM",
      }}
    >
  ...
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-datepicker-custom-empty-placeholder-format-hqp36p?file=/Demo.tsx

References:
[Custom field placeholder](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/adapters-locale/#custom-field-placeholder)

Comment: CAn you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/q/77773929/6153188