# muix-datepicker Customization: Labeling Hours and Minutes Selection

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datetimepicker, mui-x-date-picker

I am using this [muix-datepicker](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-time-picker/) and I want to add a label on the `hours` and `minutes` column. Unfortunately, the API doesn't provide this functionality.

Need help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are willing to create your own `multiSectionDigitalClock` menu items, the closest you can get is to customize the [PickersLayout](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/custom-layout/#dom-customization) to add an additional grid row for the labels.

However, the problem with this approach is that you won't be able to align these labels with the `multiSectionDigitalClock` without some hard-coded width for its columns, as the calendar and the clock are wrapped together as a single grid cell. Here, I use `width=3.5rem` for each column.

Optionally, you could add some negative top margin to the `ContentWrapper` and add a background (perhaps `inherit`) and z-index on the labels to hide the numbers that scrolls over it.

[Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stoic-nobel-h2r5sj?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrf9wugv0006356h19oyesd5%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrf9wugu0002356hs8ww98th%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrf9wugu0003356hmcdszwjp%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrf9wugu0005356h7cvyphfy%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clrf9wugu0002356hs8ww98th%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrf9wugu0001356hqb7ju4md%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrf9wugu0002356hs8ww98th%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrf9wugu0001356hqb7ju4md%2522%257D%252C%2522clrf9wugu0005356h7cvyphfy%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrf9wugu0004356h9h5xjrdv%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrf9wugu0005356h7cvyphfy%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrf9wugu0004356h9h5xjrdv%2522%257D%252C%2522clrf9wugu0003356hmcdszwjp%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrf9wugu0003356hmcdszwjp%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

```
const CHILD_WIDTH = "3.5rem";

function MyCustomLayout(props) {
  const { toolbar, tabs, content, actionBar } = usePickerLayout(props);
  return (
    <PickersLayoutRoot className={pickersLayoutClasses.root} ownerState={props}>
      {toolbar}
      <Box
        sx={{
          gridColumn: 2,
          display: props.wrapperVariant === "desktop" ? "flex" : "none",
          justifyContent: "end",
          textAlign: "center"
        }}
      >
        <Typography sx={{ width: CHILD_WIDTH }}>Hour</Typography>
        <Typography sx={{ width: CHILD_WIDTH }}>Min</Typography>
        <Typography sx={{ width: CHILD_WIDTH }}></Typography>
      </Box>
      <PickersLayoutContentWrapper
        sx={{
          ".MuiMultiSectionDigitalClock-root": {
            ul: {
              width: CHILD_WIDTH,
              boxSizing: "border-box"
            }
          }
        }}
      >
        {tabs}
        {content}
      </PickersLayoutContentWrapper>
      {actionBar}
    </PickersLayoutRoot>
  );
}

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
  <DateTimePicker label="Basic date time picker"
    slots={{
      layout: MyCustomLayout
    }}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```